# How do I generate the appropriate expression?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I am struggling to connect my Azure App Services to their respective App Service Plans.  Currently, I have an object that contains the name and ID of every app service plan in the configuration.  The app service requires the ID of the app service plan as part of its configuration.

I don't understand how best I can generate the necessary expression to get the right app service plan id.

In my App Service, I have tried the following defined, and it works:

`service_plan_id       =  var.app_service_plans.admin.id`

But it will connect every app service to the `admin` plan.   I need a way to change the `admin` segment when using `for_each`.  In other words, I need to call...

```
var.app_service_plans.admin.id
var.app_service_plans.storage.id
var.app_service_plans.webjobs.id
var.app_service_plans.www.id
```

... on successive `for_each` loops.

I have tried using a lookup() but that doensn't seem to cut it.

`service_plan_id     = lookup(var.app_service_plans, each.value.plan_lookup, "")`

Configuration Below

Relevant portions of the root module look like this:

```
# root module
@main.tf

module "app_service_plan" {
  source         = "./modules/my.app_service_plan"
  location       = module.resource_group.location
  environment    = var.environment
  resource_group = module.resource_group.name

  app_service_plans = var.app_service_plans
}

module "app_service" {
source         = "./modules/my.app_service"
location       = module.resource_group.location
environment    = var.environment
resource_group = module.resource_group.name

app_services    = var.app_services
app_service_plans = module.app_service_plan.plan
}

# terraform.tfvars

app_service_plans = {
  admin = {
    name = "admin"
    os_type = "Windows"
    sku_name = "P1v3"
  }

  storage = {
    name = "storage"
    os_type = "Windows"
    sku_name = "P1v3"
  }

  webjobs = {
    name = "webjobs"
    os_type = "Windows"
    sku_name = "P2v3"
  }

  www = {
    name = "www"
    os_type = "Windows"
    sku_name = "S1"
  }
}

app_services = {
  admin = {
   name                = "admin"
   plan_lookup = "admin" # matches the key in var.app_service_plans{}
  }
  storage = {
   name                = "storage"
   plan_lookup = "storage" # matches the key in var.app_service_plans{}
  }
  webjobs = {
   name                = "webjobs"
   plan_lookup = "webjobs" # matches the key in var.app_service_plans{}
  }
  www = {
   name                = "www"
   plan_lookup = "www" # matches the key in var.app_service_plans{}
  }
}
```

My app service plan module looks like:

```
# module app_service_plan
# main.tf

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "app_service_plan" {
  for_each            = var.app_service_plans
  name                = "asp-${each.value.name}-${local.name_suffix}"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
  os_type             = each.value.os_type
  sku_name            = each.value.sku_name
}

# variables.tf

variable "environment" {
  type        = string
  description = "from environment vars"
}
variable "location" {}
variable "resource_group" {}

variable "app_service_plans" {
  type = map(
    object({
      name = string
      os_type = string
      sku_name = string
    })
  )

}

# outputs.tf

output "plan" {
  value = { for k, plan in azurerm_service_plan.app_service_plan :
              k => ({"name" = plan.name, "id" = plan.id })
        }
}
```

I get an output that looks like this:

```
> module.app_service_plan
{
  "plan" = {
    "admin" = {
      "id" = "/subscriptions/**AZURE ID REDACTED**/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/asp-admin-iac-eastus"
      "name" = "asp-admin-iac-eastus"
    }
    "storage" = {
      "id" = "/subscriptions/**AZURE ID REDACTED**/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/asp-storage-iac-eastus"
      "name" = "asp-storage-iac-eastus"
    }
    "webjobs" = {
      "id" = "/subscriptions/**AZURE ID REDACTED**/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/asp-webjobs-iac-eastus"
      "name" = "asp-webjobs-iac-eastus"
    }
    "www" = {
      "id" = "/subscriptions/**AZURE ID REDACTED**/providers/Microsoft.Web/serverfarms/asp-www-iac-eastus"
      "name" = "asp-www-iac-eastus"
    }
  }
}
```

The App Service Module looks like this:

```
# module app_service
# main.tf

resource "azurerm_windows_web_app" "windows_web_app" {
  for_each            = var.app_services
  name                = "as-${each.value.name}-${local.name_suffix}"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group
  location            = var.location

## here is where the problems is ##  
  service_plan_id     = lookup(var.app_service_plans, each.value.plan_lookup, "")

  site_config {}
}

# variables.tf

variable "environment" {
  type        = string
  description = "from environment vars"
}
variable "location" {}
variable "resource_group" {}

variable "app_services" {}
variable "app_service_plans" {}
```

I don't know where to go from here, I don't even know if I am asking the right questions.  Perhaps there is a better way to skin this cat.

Comment: Have you tried `service_plan_id = var.app_service_plans[each.value.plan_lookup].id` ?

Comment: ummm...   Wow...  I didn't know I could do that.

Comment: Your `lookup()` code wasn't getting the `.id` value by the way.

Comment: I know...  I was still one level of data away from that, but couldn't figure out how I was supposed to put the each.value expression in inside the object expression.   Are you going to write up the answer so I can give you the green checkmark?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the expression like this:

```
service_plan_id = var.app_service_plans[each.value.plan_lookup].id
```